# Start monit with a stopped service

Tags: linux, monitoring, monit

Is it possible to have an entry for a service in monit where

- the service is not started on system startup and on monit startup
- and monit displays it's status
- and only starts or stops it, when I press the start or stop button in the http interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want monit to check the service in manual mode. Take a look at the keyword `mode` (hint: `manual`) in the monit man page, section [THE RUN CONTROL FILE](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#the_run_control_file).

Comment: i wonder if you can help out with my latest monit question also? http://serverfault.com/questions/121638/how-to-check-the-result-of-a-script-with-monit