# How to check the result of a script with monit?

Tags: monitoring, monit

Is there a way to check the result of a script with monit? For example a script returns 0 means ok, but 1 means failed. The idea is to call the script from monit on the local machine directly and interpret the result and send emails.

For example a script could do some hardware check.

My workaround is to call the script with cron and write the result to a file and check the file with monit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your work-around is the recommended way to do it with monit from what I've read.

Comment: Where have you read it?

Answer (score 12):

[Program status testing](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#PROGRAM-STATUS-TEST) does exactly what you want. Use it to check the status command of a script.

For example:

```
check program hwtest with path /usr/local/bin/hwtest.sh
with timeout 500 seconds
if status = 1 then alert
if status = 3 for 5 cycles then exec "/usr/local/bin/emergency.sh"
```

Comment: I get a bad file descriptor error when I do this. Do you know what could cause this?

Comment: @jeteon you may need to do something like: `"/bin/bash -c '/path/to/your/hwtest.sh'"`